# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED handshake error in vscode but works fine in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm new to flutter and had my flutter environment set up. I was using VS Code as my editor.
When i tried to request apis it threw me

`HandshakeException: Handshake error in client`

So eventually i searched it on web and found a solution

```
void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

It did the job but it was mentioned there that this was not ideal. (esp. for prod.)

After few days i tried to use Android Studio for a new project and found i had no issues requesting  APIs on Android Studio. I thought the error was fixed but when i ran the exact same code on VS Code  i got Handshake error again.

I really want to use VSCode because its really light to use.

So can anyone help me with this what is causing this issue on VS Code and why the hell exact same code works on Android Studio?

Here is the output for `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm, locale
    en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at
      /Users/dev.meena/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 135454af32 (8 weeks ago), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
    • Engine revision 3316dd8728
    • Dart version 2.18.6
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/dev.meena/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Users/dev.meena/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/213.7172.25.2113.9123335/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Users/dev.meena/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/213.7172.25.2113.9123335/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Users/dev.meena/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/221.6008.13.2211.9477386/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/dev.meena/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/223.8214.52/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
    • VS Code at /Users/dev.meena/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile) • B401E3BC-F514-4C34-B73F-B9B31B70C5E8 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.119

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I expect both environments to work similarly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you first run the api with posman or insomnia, in case you have a certificate error, contact with backend person because it is a bad server configuration

Comment: i have tried running the api on postman too man i've tested bunch of different APIs on vscode, android studio, browser and postman. The only place where i get this error is VS Code.